# How do I compare a string against a huge set of predefined strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string

In a C# program I have a `String` variable and I want to compare it against say one hundred predefined (hardcoded) string literals so that I know whether it matches any of those predefined strings.

I can of course write a `switch` or a chain of `if-else if`s but this way strings are interleaved with control statements and IMO that decreases readability and makes planting an error easier.

Is there a way to somehow list all strings so that they are located as close to each other in code as possible?

Comment: What do you intend by *list all strings* Do you mean scan the proj and find the hardcoded literals ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Nope, I will write them all myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no way but to hardcode the strings, you can define them in an HashSet:

```
var strs = new HashSet<string>{ "Str1","Str2","Str3" };
```

Ignoring case :

```
var strs = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "Str1","Str2","Str3" };
```

And :

```
var found = strs.Contains(myVariable);
```

Comment: Contains on array is O(n) so this may be too expensive.

Comment: No idea about the performance of linq in a case like this, but in general I would assume a Hash like suggested by Brian is faster.

Comment: Beware of Contains<T>(T s, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer), it is the extension method :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) (or [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)) and then just check if the key is present or not.

Comment: When do I populate the dictionary?

Comment: @Sharptooth: If you have that many values I would probably populate it from a file or db depending on your application. If that is not an option, you can populate it with hard coded strings.

Comment: My question is when do I run that population code. In C++ I'd just declare a static array and it'd be initialized when the program starts in a perfectly thread-safe manner - how do I do this in C# conveniently?

Comment: @sharptooth: I don't know exactly your code, but you could create the hashset in the static constructor of the class containing the hardcoded strings...

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I would put all these strings in a `List` and do this comparison in a `foreach` or `contains`.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways I have approached this

1. Use a List and invoke "contains" 
   or
2. Use a long string (as `string lits = "one|two|three"`) and then find then call `lits.indexOf(otherString + "|")`, if the value is greater than -1 then you have a hit...

Cheers

CEC

```
 private const string _searched = "one|two|three";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string search = "two" + "|";
            if (_searched.IndexOf(search) > -1)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }

        private List<string> _searchedList = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string search = "two";
            if (_searchedList.Contains(search))
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If performance is paramount and if the strings to search are known at compile time you can create a [minimal perfect hash](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html) and store the strings in an array.

```
var stringTable = new[] { "The", "quick", "brown", ... };
var input = "fox";
var hash = ComputeMinimalPerfectHash(input);
var match = stringTable[hash];
if (input == match)
  // You have found a match.
```

Obviously generating the code for `ComputeMinimalPerfectHash` based on the strings is the tricky part.

Answer (score 2):

If this list does not change you place them all into a collection and loop through the collection and compare the strings.

Using a switch statement or if-else ifs wouldn't be correct in the case of one hundred cases.

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary of (string, string), add all your predefined strings with the key and value as the same string. You can use dictionary.ContainsKey() function to check if the input string exists in the dictionary.

This will also be faster than looping through all the strings and doing comparison as dictionary will use a hash function to locate the keys faster instead of looping.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>{"String 1", "String 2", "String 3" ...}; 
if (strings.Contains(stringValue))
{         
}
```